# Breeze.js Getting Error during Save

Tags: breeze

I am getting the following error when saving Data, Get works fine.
I am using VS2012,Creating MVC4 Webapi project, using `Nuget` to get the `Breeze.js`.
On the server i am using DbContext from Code First.

**ServerSide Code**

```
 [BreezeController]
    public class CountryController : ApiController
    {
        private CountryContext db = new CountryContext();


            readonly EFContextProvider<CountryContext> _contextProvider =
        new EFContextProvider<CountryContext>();

        // ~/api/todos/Metadata 
        [HttpGet]
        public string Metadata()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Metadata();
        }

        // GET api/Country
        public IQueryable<Country> GetCountries()
        {
            return db.Countries.AsQueryable();
        }

        // ~/api/todos/SaveChanges
        [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
        {
            return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class CountryContext : DbContext
    {

        public CountryContext() : base("name=CountryContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    }
```

**Header**

```
{
   "entities":[
      {
         "Country_ID":1,
         "Country_Code":"USA modified",
         "Country_Name":"Unites states hjk",
         "entityAspect":{
            "entityTypeName":"Country:#LearnKnockout.Models",
            "entityState":"Modified",
            "originalValuesMap":{
               "Country_Name":"Unites states"
            },
            "autoGeneratedKey":{
               "propertyName":"Country_ID",
               "autoGeneratedKeyType":"Identity"
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "saveOptions":{
      "allowConcurrentSaves":false
   }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
   "$id":"1",
   "$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
   "Message":"An error has occurred.",
   "ExceptionMessage":"Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'.",
   "ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException",
   "StackTrace":" at Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider 1.get_ObjectContext()\r\n at Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider 1.ProcessSaves(Dictionary2 saveMap)\r\n at Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider 1.SaveChangesCore(Dictionary2 saveMap)\r\n at Breeze.WebApi.ContextProvider.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)\r\n at LearnKnockout.Controllers.CountryController.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) in c:\\Users\\nssidhu\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\CountryWebAPI\\CountryWebAPI\\Controllers\\CountryController.cs:line 43\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__4()\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func 1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
}
```

Comment: Are you using code first or database first EF? If database first, are you using a DbContext instance or an ObjectContext instance in your EFContextProvider<T>?

Comment: What do you exactly want? You didn't ask any questions more info besides a stacktrace would be helpfull...

Comment: On the server, what does your DbContext or ObjectContext look like and what version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: <package id="Breeze.MVC4WebApi" version="0.80.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.0-alpha2" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: I am finding that exact same error is occuring in the Todo sample as well, i downloaded to the sample using nuget as well

Answer (score 2):

### Updated 10/28/2013:

As of now, Breeze 1.4.5 has support for Microsoft's ASP.NET WebApi 2 and Entity Framework 6. Please see http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download.

### Old post...

We have not yet tested Breeze with the Entity Framework version 6 ***alpha*** and are probably unlikely to do so until it reaches at least ***beta***.

That said, the JsonFormatter and ODataActionFilter attributes still exist in the most recent versions of breeze alongside the BreezeController attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I have a guess about how you got into this mess.

First, I'm betting that you are using the visual "Manage NuGet Packages" dialog within Visual Studio.

Second, I'll bet that you have selected "**Include Prerelease**" in the upper-left combobox. This is the only way I can reproduce your experience. Would you please check that combobox setting and comment back here for us?

If so, NuGet will install EF v.6 alpha if EF is not already in the project or upgrade EF 5 to EF 6 if it is. **Ouch!**  This can also happen if you upgrade the EF package of an existing project separately.

I strongly recommend that everyone stick to the "**Stable Only**" setting unless you're absolutely certain you want a pre-release package; and then please remember to set it back to "Stable Only" as the combobox setting is "sticky".

Yes we *could* limit the upper bound of the EF version in our NuGet package ... and maybe we will. Frankly, that is [contrary to the NuGet guidance](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Reference/Versioning), it's quite difficult to manage all of the versioning permutations, and it's important to take responsibility when deviating from the standard path.

What is unclear to me is how you acquired an older version of the ***Breeze.WebApi.dll*** that lacks the *BreezeControllerAttribute*. How did you learn of the *[BreezeController]* attribute except by installing the ***Breeze.MVC4WebApiClientSample*** NuGet package? That's the only NuGet package in which that attribute can be found ... and installing (or upgrading to) that package should have delivered the correct Breeze.WebApi.dll reference to the companion "packages" folder.

I suspect that your project file is a bit of a wreck. **You're in NuGet hell** and, unless you really know NuGet well, you're often better off rebuilding the project from scratch, copying in your custom code.

Comment: Let me tell how I got into this error. I started my project with Breeze Angular SPA template (http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/breezeangular-template). Then, I ran into a error as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909589/breeze-js-adding-an-element-to-a-navigation-property-collection-without-inverse and somebody suggested that the problem has been fixed in Breeze 1.3.5. So, that caused me to upgrade using NuGet to the latest.

Comment: That template is quite old and has not been updated for the VS2013 releases with their associated nuget packages. For the best guidance on Breeze+Angular I suggest you look instead at John Papa's Pluralsight course ["Building Apps with Angular and Breeze"](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/build-apps-angular-breeze)

Answer (score 1):

The missing method exception is thrown because of the namespace changes in EF 6.0.  Specifically these:

System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext => System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext
System.Data.EntityState => System.Data.Entity.EntityState

more info: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6

You could grab the source and modify EFContextProvider.cs to use those namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

seems like there is problem with latest Nuget Packagae(mostly with alpha version of entity FramewroK).

I uninstalled the current BreezeNuget Package and then installed the earlier version and everything is working fine(using older version i had to change attributes to Jsonformater,oDataActionfilter instead of Breezecontroller)

Install-Package Breeze.MVC4WebApi -Version 0.78.1

Comment: I seriously doubt that the [BreezeController] attribute is an issue and doubt also that reverting to the other attributes (which remain in all product versions) made any difference whatsoever. You're welcome to prove it. As said elsewhere, the Breeze.NET components have not been tried against alpha EF.  **Note to everyone: please TELL US when you're incorporating something unusual in your project**. Everyone can be more helpful to you when they know how you stepped outside the box.

Comment: When i get the Breeze Package using Nuget, it by default downloads EF alpha version, i did not do that knowingly or specifically. May be you can tie by dependency to Specific version of EF. Also i had to revert the Breeze attribute since i was using older version of Breeze, where it would not compile the Breeze attribute. I did not meant that there was problem in BreezeController, i had to revert it back simply becuase i was using older version of Breeze package.

Comment: See my answer above in which I guess at how you were able to acquire EF 6-alpha

Answer (score 0):

As [ckal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14060485/1029874) describes, you must update the EFContextProvider.cs and use the new namespaces in Entity Framework 6.

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/al222cv/6008807) with the updated code. You have to update to Entity Framework 6 in Breeze.WebApi project to get it to work.

I have tested it in my own projects and it seems to work just as before.